# C++ error returning value from a constructor

Tags: c++

I'm currently trying to make the program send only the selected option to a string function. However, I am receiving an error -

> "error returning value from a constructor" .

I tried to change it to a breakstatement, but that will print "Starter::::Description:Price". That kinda is what I want. Though, if i extend my menu do cater maincourse etc etc, it will just print "Starter:Maincourse:Drinks:Pudding:Description:Price". Which is not I want.

```
 category::category(){
 _starter = "Starter";
 _maincourse = "MainCourse";
 _pudding = "Pudding";
 _drink = "Drink";
 _itemDescription = "Item Description";
 _price = "Price";


cout << "Menu\n====\n" << endl;
cout << "(1) Starter\n(2) Main Course "
"items\n(3) Pudding.\n(4)Drink\n(5) End program\n" << endl;
cout << "Select: ";
char ch;
cin >> ch;
cin.ignore(100, '\n');
cout << endl;

switch(ch) {
case '1': 
            cout << "Item Description: ";
            getline(cin,_itemDescription);
            cout << "Price: ";
            getline(cin,_price);
return;
```

}

And the return _starter will go into a function tostring()

```
string category::tostring() {
string record = _starter + ":" + _maincourse + ":" + _pudding + ":"  + _drink + ":" + _itemDescription + ":"+ _price;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constructors and destructors can't return anything. Perhaps you can store the return value in a public property of the class the constructor is for, and provide an alternate function to get that property.

Comment: A good choice for it will be a cast operator. This way you could emulate value returning constructor almost 100%.

Comment: Am I suppose to create another class eg: `ref class Static Properties { static int returnvalue; Public: static property int static_return; } `Or have `int returnvalue;` in the `public class` where i have the attributes of starters etc?

Comment: It's really up to you, just so long as you're not trying to return a value from a constructor or destructor.

Answer (score 0):

Constructors cannot return anything (the only `return` statement allowed is one with no expression, so nothing is returned to the caller (i.e. `return;`).

A common way to report errors from a constructor is to throw an exception.